# Using existing project code in a new project

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS using existing project's class/resource files in another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660923/ios-using-existing-projects-class-resource-files-in-another-project)

I have multiple iOS projects in my Workspace. Is there a way I can use the code of existing projects in my newly created project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reuse those codes.

1.Make a static library of the function which you want to reuse.

2.Add the static library and .h files in your project.And you can call directly those functions in the static library from your new project.

You can find nice tutorial to create static library:[here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)